# Chrome Console - Object Properties don't match

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, properties, console

I am trying to access the `start` property of an `event` object and I am seeing some strange behavior, here is the relevant code:

```
console.log(event);
console.log(event.start);
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Why am I getting different values for the `start` property? I want the 9:31, but it's returning 8:26, what's going on here?

And why dont the values match between the Object Details header, and the expanded view?

Here is the returned string when I `console.log(JSON.stringify(event));`:

```
{"id":"1","title":"Meeting Test","start":"2013-12-30T16:26:00.000Z","reminder":"2013-12-30 13:58:32","source":{"url":"../someURl/somePhp.php","dataType":"json","type":"POST","data":{"action":"fetch","offset":480},"className":[]},"_id":"1","_start":"2013-12-30T16:26:00.000Z","end":null,"_end":null,"allDay":false,"className":[]}
```

Comment: Can you show your json?

Comment: @AlexShilman you want the stringified version of the event object?

Comment: Yes. The part that you're trying to get.

Comment: Did something modify the `event` object after its `start` property was logged?

Comment: @Bergi I think you have found the culprit, I was unaware of this behavior!

Comment: But this is not an array.

Comment: @AlexShilman you're right it's not an array, but the issue lies in Chromes Console, the event object was indeed being modified directly after the console.log and those are the values that we see in the expanded view. I consider it a bug, it is very misleading, good to know tho!

Comment: @AlexShilman: Check the many linked questions and duplicates of that post. The behaviour is similar for arrays as it is for objects. If you find a more canonical answer in another post, I'd be happy to close future duplicates with that.